# react native failed for task ':react-native-interactable:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to run my app on android device
I didn't try on ios, I have installed all the required dependencies.
I'm working on windows, 
this is what i did => 
react-native run-android =>
and this what i get **
ps: i already tried every solution that i have found in google but nothing worked for me so
please if you have any idea how to solve this, thanks in advance **

```
> Configure project :app
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:3: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
            @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
             ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setVerticalOnly(InteractableView view, @Nullable boolean verticalOnly) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setStartOnFront(InteractableView view, @Nullable boolean startOnFront) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setHorizontalOnly(InteractableView view, @Nullable boolean horizontalOnly) {
                                                          ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setDragEnabled(InteractableView view, @Nullable boolean dragEnabled) {
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setSnapTo(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableArray snapPoints) {
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setSprings(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableArray springs) {
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:111: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setGravity(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableArray gravityPoints) {
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setFriction(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableArray frictionAreas) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setAlertAreas(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableArray alertAreas) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:126: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setDrag(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableMap dragWithSpring) {
                                                ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:131: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setDragToss(InteractableView view, @Nullable float dragToss) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:136: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setReportOnAnimatedEvents(InteractableView view, @Nullable boolean reportOnAnimatedEvents) {
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:141: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setBoundaries(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableMap boundaries) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:146: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setInitialPosition(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableMap setInitialPosition) {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
Note: C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\physics\PhysicsBehavior.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
16 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-interactable:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 46s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-fbsdk\android\src\main\java\com\facebook\reactnative\androidsdk\Utility.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-google-signin\android\src\main\java\co\apptailor\googlesignin\RNGoogleSigninModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:3: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                 ^
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
            @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
             ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setVerticalOnly(InteractableView view, @Nullable boolean verticalOnly) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setStartOnFront(InteractableView view, @Nullable boolean startOnFront) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setHorizontalOnly(InteractableView view, @Nullable boolean horizontalOnly) {
                                                          ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setDragEnabled(InteractableView view, @Nullable boolean dragEnabled) {
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setSnapTo(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableArray snapPoints) {
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setSprings(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableArray springs) {
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:111: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setGravity(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableArray gravityPoints) {
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setFriction(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableArray frictionAreas) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setAlertAreas(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableArray alertAreas) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:126: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setDrag(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableMap dragWithSpring) {
                                                ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:131: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setDragToss(InteractableView view, @Nullable float dragToss) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:136: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setReportOnAnimatedEvents(InteractableView view, @Nullable boolean reportOnAnimatedEvents) {
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:141: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setBoundaries(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableMap boundaries) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\InteractableViewManager.java:146: error: cannot find symbol
    public void setInitialPosition(InteractableView view, @Nullable ReadableMap setInitialPosition) {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class InteractableViewManager
Note: C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\node_modules\react-native-interactable\lib\android\src\main\java\com\wix\interactable\physics\PhysicsBehavior.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
16 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-interactable:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 46s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happened to me once but on a different library after refactoring my app to androidx. i've used [jetifier](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier) to resolve it. can you try this and see if this works on your end?

steps:

1. First, use Android Studio's refactoring tool to convert your app re: the [Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)
2. `npm install --save-dev jetifier`
3. `npx jetify`
4. `npx react-native run-android` (your app should correctly compile and work)
5. Call `npx jetify` run in the postinstall target of your package.json (Any time your dependencies update you have to jetify again)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using androidX in your project. If it right, you must migrate to androidX, follow [this](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered these same errors. The problem is that react native has migrated to version 60.0+ which will now support androidX. So the libraries are having a hard life to accomodate themselves to the breaking changes.

You might be using androidX libraries or the react native may be using androidX which is causing issue to parse the libraries.

Do one thing : `import androidx.annotation.Nullable;`

Add this line to the library import which is causing this issue. You might need to add this line in node modules folder where the libraries are stored.

Answer (score 0):

You need Upgrade your source lib `react-native-interactable`

I suggest you read this link
[HERE](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder/issues/86#issuecomment-529825878)
I hope Useful for You

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I dont get it....
The answer I posted in the link is exactly the solution to the problem.Now Whats Wrong??? :(